# Dangers in using delay() in linux

Tags: c, linux, delay

In the code I'm working on, I have to run multiple different processes in Linux. Part of one of these processes is to handle a faulty battery by disconnecting it from a stack of other batteries and reconnecting it after ten seconds. Currently, I'm just using `delay(10)` but I'm wondering if that function will cause blocking or other problems. What risks are involved with this function?

Comment: Is blocking a problem for you? (Where’s `delay` defined outside of Windows, anyway?)

Comment: @Ryan Windows has a delay() API?   Sure, it has Sleep(), but not seen delay().

Comment: What I can tell you from electronics point of view - `delay` halts the code execution. So, basically it just stays there and waits.

Comment: What is `delay()`? Assuming that it does the same as [`sleep`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep), then it will only cause the calling thread sleep. Other threads will not be affected.